# Green's theorem with integral how do i solve?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image: Green's theorem]

How would i solve this? very lost please help me. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Green's theorem tells us that the line integral that you wish to compute is given by the double integral of the function $\frac{\partial (x^2+\sin y)}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial (e^{3x}+2y)}{\partial y}$ on the interior of the rectangle in the figure that you have drawn. Therefore, you need to evaluate the following double integral:

$\int_{1}^{4} \int_{2}^{6} (2x-2) dx dy$

I hope this helps!

Comment: can you show me a more detailed answer?

Comment: @jainsmit Can you compute the double integral in my answer? If you can't, then can you tell me where you are stuck? If you know how to compute integrals in single variable calculus, then I (or another user here, perhaps) would be happy to walk you through the calculation of the double integral in my answer. I think it's important that you do it yourself though (possibly with help from one of us) because that's the only way to really learn material of a computational nature like this. What is the first step that you would take in calculating: $\int_{1}^{4} \int_{2}^{6} (2x-2)dxdy$?

Comment: can we chatt about this?

Comment: i how how to do the double integral i do not know what you did to get that integral

Comment: @jainsmit I have to go in a few minutes (or rather I have to sleep in a few minutes!) so I can't chat for long. I got the double integral by Green's theorem. Green's theorem tells us that the line integral of $(e^{3x}+2y)dx+(x^2+\sin y)dy$ along the boundary of the rectangle in the counterclockwise orientation indicated is equal to the double integral of the function $h=\frac{\partial (x^2+\sin y)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial (e^{3x}+2y)}{\partial y}$ over the rectangle. However, the function $h$ is just $2x-2$ so I get the integrand and ...

Comment: ... the rectangle is defined by $2\leq x\leq 6$ and $1\leq y\leq 4$ so I get the limits of the double integral. Therefore, I get the double integral $\int_{1}^{4} \int_{2}^{6} (2x-2) dxdy$. Does that answer your question @jainsmit ?

Comment: but when you take the derivate of the h how does it equal 2x-2?

Comment: @jainsmit $\frac{\partial (x^2+\sin y)}{\partial x} = 2x$ and $\frac{\partial (e^{3x}+2y)}{\partial y}=2$ so the difference is $2x-2$.

Comment: ok that makes so much more sense thanks!!

Comment: @jainsmit You're welcome! I'm glad everything makes sense now.

Comment: @jainsmit By the way, if you're satisfied with my answer (or any other answer on this website), then it would be great if you could up-vote it (by clicking the arrow pointing upward on the left of the answer) and/or accepting it (by clicking the green tick mark just below the up arrow and down arrow on the left of the answer).

Comment: @jainsmit Thanks!

Comment: are you still up? can you help me with one more problem?

Comment: @jainsmit I wasn't online when you posted but if you still have a question, then you could ask it separately on StackExchange and I'm sure someone will answer it. I'll keep a look out for it too so once you post it I might also try to answer it if no-one else does.